# How to efficiently load multiple images dynamically from Stream?

Tags: c#, android, ios, uwp, uno-platform

I need to load and show multiple images in a list. Imagine a list of "photo albums" each containing multiple images - and I want to show a list of those albums with thumbnails of the first 4 images.

If I had the images as normal URLs, I could simply create string-property, set the URLs and bind them in XAML to the Source of an Image. The framework would handle the loading, rendering and probably caching of the images.

But I have the technical requirement of loading the image from a stream, that fetches the images via a specific logic. I'm now struggeling on how to provide the Streams in my ViewModel, so that the View only loads the Image-Streams that are to be shown and does this in an efficient way. I managed to do this by creating BitmapImages in the ViewModel and call their SetSourceAsync-Method with the corresponding streams. But I either get into Threading issues (a BitmapImage is only allowed to be created by a UI-thread it seems) or the app stutters on Android while loading the images from my stream. It seems the loading is still done on the UI-thread.

Does someone have a good way to handle this? I would even appreciate some kind of caching of those streams.

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,

TopperDEL

*** Update 09/01/2021 ***
I managed to work around this issue by using Skiasharp for rendering of the bitmaps. Basically I created a UserControl, that includes a Skiasharp "SKXamlCanvas". Once I got my stream i create an SKBitmap and Draw that on the Canvas. I haven't got any issues up until now.

The code can be seen here: [Github](https://github.com/TopperDEL/StorjPhotoGalleryUploader/blob/main/StorjPhotoGalleryUploader.Shared/Controls/SkiaSharpImageControl.xaml.cs)

Comment: Have you considered using `Worker` or `Coroutine` in viewmodel?

Comment: `(a BitmapImage is only allowed to be created by a UI-thread` Hard to believe as it is no gui element. But putting it in a view should be done on ui thread.

Comment: Yes, but it's true - if I try to create a BitmapImage in an async method that is not the UI-thread, it crashes with "wrong thread" (I only have the german error message here).

Comment: Ethan, can you elaborate more what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, but it's true - if I try to create a BitmapImage in an async method that is not the UI-thread, it crashes with "wrong thread" (I only have the german error message here)

Yep. it's by default, we can't create BitmapImage in non-uithread, for above scenario, we suggest call back to UI-thread with [dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-20348).

```
await Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    // create bitmap here 
});
```

Comment: This is what I did - and that works great on UWP itself. But as I'm using Uno here, it creates huge lags on BitmapImage.SetSourceAsync().